# iPhone: A built in way to show the user a simple warning/alert message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a custom built sign up component that I would like to enhance. I would like to show error messages before sending the data to the server (like "invalid email") using a built in alert system (other than modal) if possible. Is there any on iOS? Do I have to build one myself? I saw that some apps show a grey rectangle near the bottom of the screen, is that custom built?

Thanks!

Comment: :)) very true....tell this to the designer I work with:(. I'll try to convince him anyhow now that you made me realize this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All iOS alerts are modal (for now).  You will have to build your own if you want different functionality, but it isn't too difficult.  You can put together a little UIView with a label that is normally hidden.  Then just set the text and show it when you need to.

Comment: Indeed it's not too difficult, but wanted to be %100 sure there is not a built in non-modal alert

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code sample if you want to use Tweetbot style notifications in your application, these are non modal

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-tweetbot-like-alertpanels/